# SQL Select DATES and assign accordingly

Tags: sql, select, db2

I'm using SQL Oracle;

I want to do the following operation, if the YEAR on the column is equal to my current year then I want to assign the value of 0 to a new column called **ano**, and if it's a year ahead than current year then I want it to be 1 and so on, if it's less than the current year then I want it to be -1 and so on.

The column name that contains the date is **KALW_DATE**

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
          WHEN YEAR(KALW_DATE) > YEAR(NOW()) THEN (YEAR(KALW_DATE) - YEAR(NOW()))
          WHEN YEAR(KALW_DATE) < YEAR(NOW()) THEN (YEAR(KALW_DATE) + YEAR(NOW())
          ELSE 0
       END as ano
FROM   tablename;
```

but I get an error saying `"keyword FROM not found where expected"` also I'm connecting to DB2, if that changes anything.

Comment: Looks like your missing a closed parenthesis at the end of this string:  WHEN YEAR(KALW_DATE) < YEAR(NOW()) THEN (YEAR(KALW_DATE) + YEAR(NOW())

Comment: You are "using SQL Oracle" and "connecting to DB2"?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want:

```
SELECT (YEAR(KALW_DATE) - YEAR(NOW())) as ano
```

As for your code, the parentheses do not balance in the second `THEN` clause.

Comment: "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: with the following query SELECT (YEAR(KALW_DATE) - YEAR(NOW())) as ano FROM table;  it gives me a YEAR invalid identifier then the %s line

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a `YEAR()` function (at least not the version I'm running). You have to use the `EXTRACT()` function, like this:

```
SELECT *,
  (extract(year from KALW_DATE) - extract(year from current_date)) as ano
FROM   tablename;
```